# animator component not playing animation on navmeshagent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm a real noob, I am an artist that just started out programming and have looked around a lot for a solution to this, the closest i could find was a reddit post with the same problem as mine but even there no one could find a solution.

I have set up an animator controller and have given it all the parameters i need, walking, running, jumping etc. If I use a player controller script everything works like a charm. Now when I want to turn this character into an NPC and place the patrol AI script I picked up from the unity manual, things aren't working right.

I have baked my navmesh, I have added the NavMeshAgent component too. The NPC slides around, but the animation doesn't play

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using System.Collections;


public class Patrol : MonoBehaviour
{

    Animator animator;
    public Transform[] points;
    private int destPoint = 0;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;


    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

        // Disabling auto-braking allows for continuous movement
        // between points (ie, the agent doesn't slow down as it
        // approaches a destination point).
        agent.autoBraking = false;

        GotoNextPoint();
    }


    void GotoNextPoint()
    {
        // Returns if no points have been set up
        if (points.Length == 0)
            return;

        // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
        agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;

        // Choose the next point in the array as the destination,
        // cycling to the start if necessary.
        destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Length;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        // Choose the next destination point when the agent gets
        // close to the current one.
        if (!agent.pathPending && agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
            GotoNextPoint();
        
    }
}
```

[A screenshot of the animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLWHz.png)

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the object's animator?

Comment: @nullFoo I've added the image to the post

Comment: Could you put the SetBool Method from Update to GotoNextPoint?

Comment: @SoroushHosseinpour putting it in GoToNextPoint doesn't seem to work either

Comment: you can check the animator in runtime if you open its window and click on the gameObject with animator component. see if animator is playing

Comment: @SoroushHosseinpour Looking at the animator at runtime I can see that the animation is not being played

Comment: create another animator and add just the idle and run animation to it and make the transition, see if it works

Comment: @SoroushHosseinpour it works with the new animator, so i guess the problem was with the previous animator itself; it kept playing the idle animation instead of run. I did check all the transitions to see if I messed up the conditions somewhere, but they all seem to be in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animator starts from the default state (indicated by orange color) and transitions happen based on that. Based on the screenshot of your animator, from your default state, animator can go to Idle, SwordSlash and SwordJump states and there is no transition between the Idle state and the Run state. Nevertheless your code sets the isRunning bool to true. If you want it to work you must set the isWalking bool to true, so the animator goes into SwordWalk state. From there you can set isRunning to true to go to Run animation. Another way is to change isRunning to isWalking (By the way, I suggest you study about 1D blend trees)

Comment: For now I added transitions directly to and fro the idle to run animations. Thanks a lot for helping me out and thank you for the suggestion as well, I do plan on studying blend trees soon as well!